# (Pandas) TypeError: mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'level'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

So, I have this data:

[image]

And, when I try to to get mean value using `level` parameter:

`data.mean(level='type')`

I got this error:

> TypeError: mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'level'

Why is that happening? Is `level` parameter removed? If it's removed, is there any alternative to `level`?

Answer (score 0):

The `mean` function does not have a parameter called `type`. Instead, this should work:

```
mean_values = data.groupby(level='type').mean()
```